# Выполнение команды в фоновом режиме (php)

Tags: php

Как запустить выполнение команды в фоновом режиме на PHP. Например, есть компонент комментариев, и подписанные пользователи должны получать уведомления о новом комментарии сразу после публикации нового комментария.

Но чтобы пользователь, разместивший новый комментарий, не ждал окончания рассылки всем подписчикам и даже мог закрыть браузер.

Как правильно создать список рассылки для нескольких пользователей в фоне. Можно ли обойтись без CRON? Где об этом можно почитать или в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Попробуйте запустить демона

Comment: Так Вам веб-сокет нужен...

Comment: А если отправить AJAX не нуждающийся в ответе? Теоретически сервер в любом случае отработает задачу. Какие могут быть подводные камни?

Comment: Можешь воспользоваться rabbitmq.com , для асинхронного выполнения скриптов

Comment: @VladimirGonchar каким местом тут вебсокет?

Comment: @MaXX **любые**. Сообщать пользователю об успешности добавления комментария следует только после успешного добавления.

Comment: @Ипатьев Так это типичная логика вебсокета. Есть отправитель, есть несколько слушателей. Отправитель шлёт что-то - все слушатели получают.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar тут речь о почтовой рассылке. Для показа оповещений на сайте ни подписка, ни тем более фоновый режим не нужны

Comment: @Ипатьев Нет ни слова о почтовой рассылке. Оповещения на сайте - ДА, нужен сокет! Вы как будете проверять у слушателя, что пришли оповещения? Бесконечно долбиться по AJAX на сервер? Удачи с распределением нагрузки тогда)

Comment: Речь идет о оповещении в виде почтовой рассылки. Вообщем темный лес для меня. Консоль, сокеты, демоны и тд. Теоретически такие задачи нужно выполнять при создании конкретного веб-ресурса почти с нуля. Я же изобретаю велосипед на cms. Задачу для себя я решил, но все же не доволен результатом. `protected function php_async($url) {
  $fp = fopen($url, 'r');
  stream_set_blocking($fp, 0);
  $data = fgets($fp, 8192);
  fclose($fp);
  return strlen($data);
 }` . Таким образом я запустил рассылку вызвав определенный урл.